# How to store and validate requests/responses using restAssured

Tags: rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have a complex API, where I need to send get/post requests and validate the responses. So it is more complex, than validating the response code, or the body contains some string.

How can I store json file and handle them as object using restassured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct, the problem is creating the complex payload for POST and verifying the response JSON.

Serialization and De-serialization can help you out here.

What I meant by that you can create JSON payload from a java pojo (model file) and the vice-versa. So every-time you want to create a complex payload, just use GSON to serialize your model file to json. If you want to verify a specific part of a response, de-serialize that to the corresponding model file and then use getters() to extract the exact info.

RestAssured has inbuilt mechanism to do so. I prefer google's GSON for the same. Just go thru GSON documentation.

The below link might help.

```
http://toolsqa.com/rest-assured/deserialize-json-response-to-an-array-or-list/
```

If you want to verify the response status, call the `getStatusCode()` of `Response` class.

Comment: Make sense, thank you, but I need to create the pojo model file according to the json. Is there any easy way to do that? Any instruction link? Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of free online tools and libraries that can generate POJO from a json. e.g. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Somebody just mentioned here, Pojo is not the best option for complex API tests. What do you think?

Comment: POJO does not test anything. It just models your json, just a way to serialize and de-serialize the json to java object and vice-versa. If you use POJO, creating json will be easier and validating your response json will be much more easier even. I would suggest try both the options, then you will realize which way to proceed ahead.